# What identifier is meant in the Bitlocker recovery key document?

Tags: bitlocker

when turning on bitlocker for a device, the following recovery key document is created:

> BitLocker Drive Encryption recovery key
>
> To verify that this is the correct recovery key, compare the start of
>   the following identifier with the identifier value displayed on your
>   PC. Identifier:
>
> 8dd91aa1-55a3-4A41-8B0D-4531B127A2F0
>
> If the above **identifier matches the one displayed by your PC**, then use
>   the following key to unlock your drive. Recovery Key:
>
> 654321-987654-951846-7194568-654321-987654-951846-7194568
>
> If the above identifier doesn't match the one displayed by your PC,
>   then this isn't the right key to unlock your drive.
>
> Try another recovery key, or refer to
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=260589 for additional
>   assistance.

What identifier is meant here?

Comment: Windows 8.1 (that might matter). Since different drives result in different identifiers, i guess it is a drive identifier. "Each key package will work only for a drive that has the corresponding drive identifier." from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj647767.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The identifier of the drive is generated when the drive is encrypted.  This allows you, the end user, to identify which recovery key goes to which encrypted drive.

The reason the message says to "compare the start of the following identifier with the identifier value displayed on your PC." is because of how Bitlocker Recovery itself works.

[image]

Notice the Recovery Key **Id**entifier part of the screenshot.

One would normally save the recovery key with the identifier in the filename like so.

[image]
[image]

[How to Unlock a Drive using BitLocker Recovery in Windows 8 and 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/21433-bitlocker-recovery-unlock-drive-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: I burrowed the images, I no longer have a Windows 8.1 virtual machine at my disposal, not that it matters I don't use Bitlocker on my system drive.

Comment: also to add, if you run `Manage-bde -protectors -get c:` (or whatever drive letter you need) in an elevated shell you can retrieve both the ID and the recovery code which is useful to know beforehand whether you actually have the correct recov file.

Comment: @My1 thanks, this is what I was looking for 

Answer (score 1):

From a command line ran as an administrator, run the following command:

`manage-bde -protectors -get <drive letter>`

Example:

`manage-bde -protectors -get C:`

Look for **Numerical password ID:**